# Firefox silent addon update

Tags: firefox, firefox-addon, updates

what are the technics to update an addon in Firefox? 
I want an update method, that will not inform users about whole process.

In Chrome it works fine, you just need to update your extension in the Chrome Web Store and in few minutes your extension is being updated in browser.

Is it possible, to accomplish an update for firefox without using addons.mozilla?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Firefox switched to silent updates for add-ons a while ago, by default the user isn't notified about updates - same as in Chrome. Restartless extensions ([bootstrapped](https://developer.mozilla.org/de/docs/Extensions/Bootstrapped_extensions) or based on the [Add-on SDK](https://addons.mozilla.org/developers/builder)) will be updated immediately, classic add-ons will be updated on the next browser restart.

As to the update mechanism: extensions that aren't being distributed through addons.mozilla.org can provide a custom `updateURL` value. This URL will be queried regularly to find updates to your add-on. The update mechanism is [well-documented](https://developer.mozilla.org/en/docs/Extension_Versioning,_Update_and_Compatibility#Automatic_Add-on_Update_Checking).